# Hiding items or implementing a search feature in wxTreeCtrl

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

This question is a different question from [Finding certain child in wxTreeCtrl and updating TreeCtrl in wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919992/finding-certain-child-in-wxtreectrl-and-updating-treectrl-in-wxpython).

My overall goal:

I am using a wxTreeCtrl in C++, and I would like to implement a feature whereby a user can easily search a large tree for items containing certain text.

My preferred implementation:

Ideally, the user would initiate a search (either by pressing F3 or ctrl-F) then begin typing. As they type, items not matching the text would dynamically disappear from the tree, causing the tree to visibly shrink. This way, the results would be collected together on screen for the convenience of the user. If the user altered the search text, the relevant tree items would appear or disappear accordingly.

My question:

Is there some way to hide certain tree items, causing the tree to shrink? Or is there some other search / filtering feature implemented in wxTreeCtrl?

Answer (score -1):

@Rocketmagnet,

There is wxSearchCtrl. Did you try it.

Also check the forums.wxwidgets.org. There are multiple posts about search feature implementation.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, however, you have missed the point of the question. I'm not asking about how to make a search box to type text into. I'm asking about making the tree change appearance by hiding certain items.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet, from the content of your question this is the impression I got. So what kind of tree it is? Also - wxTextCtrl does support autocorrection - you can see it in action in the widgets sample text tab. If you are not working with the text autocompletion - you should create a new question stating the problem clearly.

Comment: It's a wxTreeCtrl, as stated in the question. My question clearly states: "Is there some way to hide certain tree items, causing the tree to shrink? Or is there some other search / filtering feature implemented in wxTreeCtrl?" This is not a question about making a search box, or about autocorrection.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet, how big is the tree? Do you want the item disappearing even if the container branch is not expanded? Also, hiding items in the tree is not possible - you should remove them i the GUI and try calling `Layout()` to update the size of the tree and when you done with the search - recreate the control completely, calling `Layout()` again. That's the only way.